# Find the limit of the expression $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}\right)^{1/\ln(1+x^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}\right)^{1/\ln(1+x^2)}$ I have tried to do this: it is equal to $e^{\lim\frac{\log{\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}}}{\log(1+x^2)}}$, but I can't calculate this with the help of l'Hopital rule or using Taylor series, because there is very complex and big derivatives, so I wish to find more easier way. 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\log{\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}}}{\log(1+x^2)}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log1 + \frac{-\frac{1}{3}x^2}{1+\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^2)}}{\log(1+x^2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{-\frac{1}{3}x^2}{1+\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^2)} + o(\frac{-\frac{1}{3}x^2}{1+\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^2)})}{x^2+o(x^2)}$$ using Taylor series. Now I think that it's not clear for me how to simplify $o\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{3}x^2}{1+\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^2)}\right)$.

Comment: This is not a homework solving site. Please see [the help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help). In particular, show effort and expect to do the work

Comment: Why don't you try the usual approach of taking logarithm and let us know if you face any problems? Just giving a problem statement is not encouraged here.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen We can also give an help for homework as hint and suggestion without give a full solution.

Comment: @J_G Let follow the given hint, what do you obtain?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yes, I agree with you, indeed the point is not whether it is a homework or not, the point is that the asker must be pushed to do the main work on that.

Comment: Now that you have effectively taken logs and also used $e$ just focus on the exponent itself. Do you recall any standard limits by looking at the denominator $\log(1+x^2)$?

Comment: @J_G I think that here Taylor's series is the most direct way. Are you aware about that?

Comment: If you look carefully both numerator and denominator are log expressions which tend to $0$ and hence they can be simplified by the use of the same standard limit and you should try to proceed in that manner.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Do you argree to proceed by Taylor's series or you would suggest also different ways?

Comment: @gimusi: I only want the asker to do some simplification via standard limits to reach a point after which both Taylor and L'Hospital's Rule can be used with almost equal ease (Taylor being slightly easier).

Comment: @J_G It would be helpful if you can also shown your work here with the full resolution. We'll take a look to that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes I agree indieed the initial set up is fully correct, maybe he wasn't aware how to deal with the two expansions in order to obtain one single expansion for the $\sin x/\arcsin x$ term.

Comment: @J_G There is somethign wrong in your derivation. Start from here $$\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}=\left(1-\frac16x^2+o(x^2)\right)\left(1+\frac16x^2+o(x^2)\right)^{-1}$$ and apply binomial series expansion to the term $$\left(1+\frac16x^2+o(x^2)\right)^{-1}=1-\frac16x^2+o(x^2)$$ then proceed with the product.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen What do you think about the way followed here to deal with such kind of question? I think the asker is fully motivated to proceed in the solution by him/herself.

Comment: @J_G that first step seems wrong$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\log{\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}}}{\log(1+x^2)}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log1 + \frac{-\frac{1}{3}x^2}{1+\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^2)}}{\log(1+x^2)}...$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That's fine from your side thanks. Often people here are fast to downvote but also after an answer has been improved they usually don't remove the downvotes. Now there are also 4 votes for close the OP. I think that up to now the question does not deserve that. Thanks again, Bye.

Comment: @J_G As a reference to proceed after you did the simplification according to the last comment, take also a look [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2717908/505767). Let me know where you are stucked at.

Comment: @J_G You should not accept an answer if you have not solved your problem. Let us know if you can now proceed to obtain a solution. Thanks

Comment: @gimusi Please stop spamming the chat. It is quite annoying. If you would like to discuss something, open a chat room.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yes sorry, you are right! I’ll follow your suggestion! Bye

Comment: @J_G Do not give up! Show your work again, we'll take a look to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

By Taylor's series

$$\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}=\frac{x-\frac16x^3+o(x^3)}{x+\frac16x^3+o(x^3)}=\frac{1-\frac16x^2+o(x^2)}{1+\frac16x^2+o(x^2)}=$$$$=\left(1-\frac16x^2+o(x^2)\right)\left(1+\frac16x^2+o(x^2)\right)^{-1}$$

Can you continue form here using binomial series for the last term?

Comment: This won't help as it leads to indeterminate form $1^{\infty} $. Or may be you wanted to emphasize that it is a particular indeterminate form.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes it was just a hint to start with. Do you think it too small?

Comment: It will help if the asker knows how to deal with $1^{\infty} $ and unless the asker says anything we can't be sure.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh After the editing, I've added a different hint to start with using Taylor's series.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to find the limit
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}}{\ln(1+x^2)}.$$
Perhaps a reasonable strategy would be to split this into calculating several simpler limits.
We know that 
\begin{gather*}
\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}}{\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}-1}=1\\
\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}=1
\end{gather*}
so we eventually get to the limit
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\frac{\sin x}{\arcsin x}-1}{x^2} =\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-\arcsin x}{x^2\arcsin x}.$$
If we also use that $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\arcsin x}x=1$, we get that
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-\arcsin x}{x^3}.$$
And now we can try to calculate separately the two limits
\begin{align*}
L_1&=\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\\
L_2&=\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{x-\arcsin x}{x^3}
\end{align*}
Both $L_1$ and $L_2$ seem as limits where L'Hospital's rule or Taylor expansion should lead to result. In fact, substitution $y=\sin x$ transforms $L_2$ to a limit very similar to $L_1$.

You can probably find also some posts on this site at least for $L_1$ (and maybe also for $L_2$). For example:
[Solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/856030), 
[Find the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arcsin x -x}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2128621),
[Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333).

Comment: +1 this is what I was suggesting in comments. A little algebraic manipulation combined with standard limits always helps.